Problem with changing the interface using Published variables
There's an issue with the variables marked as Published. For some reason, changing them doesn't trigger a UI update.
Hello everyone, I encountered the following issue. I created boolean variables in the ViewModel to control the display of a UI section. The variables are marked as Published. In the code, I explicitly specify that the variables are being modified on the main thread, where the UI should be updated. However, for some reason, nothing happens. On the other hand, if I make these variables Binding and pass them from ContentView, the UI updates without any issues, and everything works fine. What could be the problem, and how can I explicitly tell Swift to redraw the UI at this moment?
Here's the link to my GitHub project, the branch with the current code CoreData/Error - https://github.com/AlexeyRy/MenuPOP/tree/CoreData/Error

The odds of someone going to your GitHub to help you are pretty low. SO is meant to be all inclusive and links are generally used to augment. I suggest creating an MRE of your issue and since you are using CoreData try an use the basic Item that is provided by apple so anyone can copy/paste your code into an empty project

Use State for your view data. Published is for models.

I checked out the GitHub project. If that course taught you that I'd ask for a refund. It's full of memory leaks and too many objects.
